# Как добавить содержимое регистра bl и bh в регистр ax в ассемблере?

Tags: ассемблер

как переместить регистр BL в первую половину регистра AX, а регистр BH в вторую половину регистра AX ?

Comment: Что означает слово «переместить» в данном контексте? Скопировать?

Comment: @VladD, вроде логично, что переместить означает скопировать? Команда-то происходит от `move`.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну, для меня «переместить» — это «сделать, чтобы было в новом месте, а в старом исчезло». Наподобие семантики C++.

Comment: @VladD означает скопировать

Comment: @Lopatin Vitaly Что есть "первая половина" AX, и что есть "вторая половина" AX?

Comment: @Lopatin Vitaly И в чем разница между "добавить" и "переместить"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
mov ah, bl
mov al, bh
```

Comment: я использую ассемблерную вставку в с++ ...  результат возвращаю в unsigned short ..  получается я должен увидеть 12  ushort getValue(ushort a, ushort b)
{
 __asm
 {
  mov bl, 1
  mov bh, 2
  mov ah, bl
  mov al, bh
 }
} (т.е. 12 ) , но отображется 258 ... как исправить ?

Comment: @LopatinVitaly, не важно что ты используешь. Важно как ты описываешь проблему в заданном вопросе. От этого зависит качество ответа.

Comment: @LopatinVitaly, нет, 258 - это правильно. Не путай числа и строки, а также системы счисления.

Comment: @LopatinVitaly, я подозреваю, что вы выводите в десятичной системе, а нужно в 16-ричной: 258 это 0x102.

Comment: Влад, зачем слово "попробуйте" в ответе?

Comment: @АнтонСазонов: [Авторский стиль](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A10105+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5) же :)

Answer (score 4):

Возможно, так http://ideone.com/Ld4VBc

```
mov ax, bx
shl ax, 8
mov al, bh
```

Или так http://ideone.com/t2sTK7

```
mov ax, bx
ror ax, 8
```

Или ещё двумя способами из комментариев.

Спасибо @insolor за проверку:
[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Если уж `mov al, bh`, то почему тогда не просто `mov ah, bl; mov al, bh`?

Comment: Можно и `mov ax, bx; xchg ah, al` до кучи.

Comment: @VladD, потому что я ступил. Я сначала хотел по половинам `eax` распихать (а там нужный кусок не адресуется, кажется), потом перечитал вопрос. Предлагаю тебе опубликовать ответом.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Не, я даже не знаю, откомпилируется ли. Сошлись на меня в обновлении. // О, вроде компилируется: http://ideone.com/9w8vGm

Comment: @VladD, да. http://ideone.com/WnSquU - у тебя же правильная логика - раз можно разные части ставить, то можно и в другом порядке их поставить.

Comment: @АнтонСазонов, если вы считаете, что ответ "не в тему", никто не мешает вам проголосовать соответствующим образом. Другие участники могут считать по-другому, как бы вас это не настораживало. Я со своей "колокольни" (некоторого опыта программирования на асме и дизассемблирования) считаю ответ качественным.